# JOIN with two result sets from same table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite DB which is part of a PVR app. One of the tables (epg_event) holds all of the data for TV shows.

I'm trying to write a query which will return the Now/Next shows in a single record for both Now and Next.

I can query both individually easily enough.

The Now query on its own looks like this...

```
SELECT now.channel_oid as _id,
       now.oid as now_oid,
       now.title as now_title,
       now.start_time as now_start_time,
       now.end_time as now_end_time
FROM epg_event now
WHERE  now.start_time <= datetime('now') AND now.end_time > datetime('now')
ORDER BY now.channel_oid
```

This works great and in tests I get what I need. Example...

```
_id      now_oid     now_title   now_start_time         now_end_time
10029    16365522    BBC News    2014-05-21 00:45:00    2014-05-21 05:00:00
10030    16365900    Making Art  2014-05-21 03:00:00    2014-05-21 04:00:00
...
```

The Next query on its own looks like this...

```
SELECT next.channel_oid as _id,
       next.oid as next_oid,
       next.title as next_title,
       MIN(next.start_time) as next_start_time,
       next.end_time as next_end_time
FROM epg_event next
WHERE next.start_time > datetime('now')  
GROUP BY next.channel_oid
```

This also returns the correct results for the Next TV shows.

The problem I'm having is I'm trying to combine the two queries to return a single record for each channel with both the Now and Next data but I can't work out how to do it. I'm figuring I need to use a JOIN of some sort but my SQLite tools keep throwing up errors whenever I try it.

Ideally what I'm trying to do is get a single _id column in each row and combine the now/next columns into the row so I have the following columns...

```
_id  now_oid  now_title  now_start_time  now_end_time  next_oid  next_title  next_start_time  next_end_time
```

Is it possible to use a JOIN on two queries from the same table or should I be using something else?

Comment: Why don't you use a row_over query. They are designed with instances like this. Search for row over with partition and next. The internet is rife with code examples.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne : OK, I'll take a look. SQL isn't my strong point and anything other than basic queries always give me headaches.

Comment: Here is quite a good example:  http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-select-previous-and-next-rows-with-current-row-in-tsql.aspx

Comment: @AnthonyHorne : Thanks but that example seems to be for T-SQL and I'm using SQLite. I searched for row over queries on Google and it doesn't look like SQLite supports them.

Comment: Right you are. Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne : No problem thanks for trying anyway. I think I've got a solution based on the response from Lennart - I need to review the result set but at first glance it looks right. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to Lennart for pointing me in the right direction. It took some trial and error but I'm now getting exactly what I was aiming for.

```
SELECT A.channel_oid AS _id, A.oid AS now_oid, A.title AS now_title,
       A.start_time AS now_start_time, A.end_time AS now_end_time,
       B.oid AS next_oid, B.title AS next_title, B.start_time AS next_start_time,
       B.end_time AS next_end_time
FROM (
    SELECT channel_oid,
        oid,
        title,
        start_time,
        end_time
    FROM epg_event
    WHERE  start_time <= datetime('now') AND end_time > datetime('now')
    ORDER BY channel_oid) AS A  
JOIN (
    SELECT channel_oid,
        oid,
        title,
        MIN(start_time) as start_time,
        end_time
    FROM epg_event
    WHERE start_time > datetime('now')  
    GROUP BY channel_oid)  AS B 
ON A.channel_oid = B.channel_oid
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that `channel_oid, oid` is a candidate key. In it's simplest form you can join the two queries as in (untested):

```
SELECT A._id, A.now_oid, ..., B.title, ...
FROM (
    SELECT now.channel_oid,
        now.oid,
        now.title,
        now.start_time,
        now.end_time,
    FROM epg_event now
    WHERE  now.start_time <= datetime('now') AND now.end_time > datetime('now')
) AS A
JOIN (
    SELECT next.channel_oid,
        next.oid,
        next.title,
        MIN(next.start_time) as start_time,
        next.end_time 
    FROM epg_event next
    WHERE next.start_time > datetime('now')  
    GROUP BY next.channel_oid
) AS B
    ON A.channel_oid = B.channel_oid
   AND A.oid = B.oid
ORDER BY A.channel_oid
```

Comment: This constantly give syntax error near FROM (I did remove the ... from your example and replaced them with corresponding values).

Comment: I don't have sqllite so I cannot try it my self. Try `SELECT A.channel_oid
FROM (
    SELECT now.channel_oid,
        now.oid,
        now.title,
        now.start_time,
        now.end_time,
    FROM epg_event now
    WHERE  now.start_time <= datetime('now') AND now.end_time > datetime('now')
) AS A`

Comment: Same error. I'd already tried cutting it back like that. Perhaps it's a SQLite thing.

Comment: If you put up your table definitions as an sqlfiddle I can have a look

Comment: I think I've cracked it based on your query. Not sure what I changed but it looks like I've got what I need. I just need to review the result set to be sure.

Comment: I've given you upvote for helping out but I couldn't accept it as an answer as I couldn't get it to work as it was. It was enough to give me a template to go on though. Thanks, it was giving me a real headache.